# Decorators suppressing 'unfilled parameter' warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Below code would produce a visual yellow warning in PyCharm, because of the missing arguments of `f()` inside `g()`.

```
def f(b):
    return b

def g():
    return f()
#           ^
#           |___ A warning here
```

Which is great, since i want to see it and fix it easily whenever i modify  the parameters of `f()`.

However if i use a decorator on `f()`, this warning disappears:

```
def some_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@some_decorator
def f(b):
    return b


def g():
    return f()
#            ^
#            |___ no warning
```

I m guessing this happens since a decorator could be providing those needed arguments to `f()`.

Is there a way to make PyCharm ignore decorators in above scenario and keep on displaying the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `g()` to either snippet and running gives

```
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I cannot answer for sure that you cannot have PyCharm ignore the decorator (check the PyCharm doc), but in my opinion it should not.  The `f()` call in `g` calls the wrapper, not the wrappee, and the wrapper has an unconstrained generic signature.  As you said yourself, the wrapper could (and some wrappers do) manipulate `args` or `kwargs` before calling the wrapped function.  In other words, I think you are expecting too much. Statics code checks are not a substitute for writing and running tests.